Why is this code not checking the validity of the passcode?
The checkValidity function does not work and there is no alert dialogue box that appears, I want so that the passcode entered by the user is compared with the constant "Pass"


const Pass = '2207'

function checkValidity() {
  const pass_code = document.getElementById("passcode").value;
  if (pass_code == Pass) {
    alert("Correct Passcode!");
  } else {
    alert("Wrong Passcode!");
  }
}
<div id="display">
  <p style="color:black">Enter your Passcode:</p>
  <input id="passcode" type="password">
  <button onclick="checkValidity()">Enter↵</button>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>




because checkValidity is a reserved word. change your name to checkPassword or anything else. Change also <div id="display">  to <div id="Pasword-div">...

change the function name to checkTheValidity() and it will work it is a reserved name. check this SO answer link

if Pass is part of the source code, than it is not a secret. Everyone can read the source code and use it. Password verification should always be performed on the server side.

checkValidity is an existing method, so it is a reserved word1 your function is being shadowed by it. That's why it isn't running. So two solutions: one that works and one that is even better.
The first one is simply to rename your function. Voilà.
The second one is this: avoiding handling events through inline attribute assignment, and using addEventListener instead. It has several advantages (see References). The following code works perfectly:


const pass = '2207'

const button = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("button"))[0];
button.addEventListener("click", checkPassword);

function checkPassword() {
  const pass_code = document.getElementById("passcode").value;
  if (pass_code == pass){
    alert("Correct Passcode!");
  }

  else{
    alert("Wrong Passcode!");
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 195); text-align: center">
  <div id="display">
    <p style="color:black">Enter your Passcode:</p>
    <input id="passcode" type = "password">
    <button>Enter↵</button>
  </div>
  <script src = "script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



1 As pointed out by Jaromanda, that statement is wrong.

P.S. Best practices also recommend trying to avoid inline styling, and using internal/external CSS instead.
P.S. 2 As I said in my comment, established convention recommends not starting variable names with a capital letter (unless you're declaring a class or constructor).
References

addEventListener
checkValidity


Despite two answers claiming so, checkValidity is NOT a reserved word in javascript
Consider this:


// here is your checkValidity function
function checkValidity() {
  console.log("I am global");
}

// think of this function x being the execution context of `onevent="...."`
function x() {
  function checkValidity() {
    console.log("I am inside x");
  }
  // think of this being the function called in `onclick="checkValidity()"`
  checkValidity();
}
x();



No surprise that the output is I am inside x, right. If you don't understand up to here, I suggest you learn why this is the case.
When using onclick="checkValidity()" (in this question) the execution context of checkValidity() is such that the HTMLButtonElement instance method checkValidity is called, rather than the global function you declared of the same name.

easiest fix is to use a function name that isn't a method name of HTMLButtonElement in the onclick and the javascript
alternative fix is to use onclick="globalThis.checkValidity()" and leave the javascript function as is
best (modern practice, in my opinion) fix is to use addEventListener to avoid such issues in the first place, then you can call your function (almost) anything you like


The problem is that you are using a reserved word to name your function. I tried changing the name of the function and it works.
function checkIfValid(){
    console.log("testFunction");
    const pass_code = document.getElementById("passcode").value;
    if(pass_code === pass){
        alert("passcode is correct!");
    }
    else console.log("passcode is incorrect!");
}

Another problem is also the usage of a capitalized P for Pass variable. Try to use a lowercase p when naming variables. Also, use '===' instead of '==' as it also compare types (in your case both types are string, but just in case, use '==='.)

Another problem is also the usage of a capitalized P for Pass variable why is that a problem?

I know a Paola Tili :)

Its just a good programming practice that you should not name variables using capital letters. It's not that you can't, but that you should not.

I think it's the one you know Michel :)
